# The first menu is not showing in mat-toolbar if its sub menu is empty by using angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to create a nested menus. The top menu bar has 4 elements.

```
DevFestFL
Disney
Orlando
Maleficent
```

The first one doesn't have child menu and the rest of them have children. Now the issue is the first menu is not showing or its color is eaten by the background color. I think that I may need to change the code but not sure.

```
    <mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <span *ngFor="let child of items">
    <!-- Handle branch node menu items -->
    <span *ngIf="child.children && child.children.length > 0">
      <button mat-menu-item color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu">
        <mat-icon>{{child.iconName}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{child.label}}</span>
      </button>
      <app-menu-item #menu [items]="child.children"></app-menu-item>
    </span>
    <!-- Handle leaf node menu items -->
    <span *ngIf="!child.children || child.children.length === 0">
      <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="child.route">
        <mat-icon>{{child.iconName}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{child.label}}</span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu-nn9sar?file=app/menu-item/menu-item.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below style in app.component.scss, It will fix the issue.

```
  .menu-bar .mat-button.mat-primary {
    color: white;
  }
```

Check the modified working code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu-j4hu3k?file=app/app.component.scss